# Find the probability that A drew it on the first draw

Tags: probability

A and B draw coins in turn without replacement from a bag containing $3$ dimes and $4$ nickels. A draws first. It is known that A drew the first dime. Find the probability that A drew it on the first draw.

I know that the probability of drawing the first dime on the first draw must be $\frac{3}{7}$. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Are you asking if your conclusion is correct? Because if you know the correct answer, why are you asking us about it :P

Comment: This is a conditional probability problem. You have to divide your answer by the probability that $A$ drew the first dime.

Answer (score 2):

P$[$A draws dime on first draw draws first dime$|$ A draws first dime$]=\dfrac{P(\mbox{A draws dime on the first draw })}{P(\mbox{A draws first dime})}$

So, $$P(\mbox{A draws dime on first draw})=\dfrac37$$

Since, there are only $3$ dimes,  in order for $A$ to draw the first dime, this must happen on $A$'s first,second or third draw.  Thus, we need$$P(\mbox{A draws first dime})=P(\mbox{A draws dime on first draw})+P(\mbox{A draws first dime on second draw})+P(\mbox{A draws first dime on third draw.})$$

$$P(\mbox{A draws dime on second draw})=\dfrac47\cdot\dfrac36\cdot\dfrac35=\dfrac{6}{35}$$Because $A$'s first draw is one of the four non-dimes and $B$'s first draw is on of th three remaining non-dimes after $A$'s draw, and $A$'s second draw is one of the three dimes of the five remaining coins. Similarly, $$P(\mbox{A draws first dime on the third draw})=\dfrac47\cdot\dfrac36\cdot\dfrac25\cdot\dfrac14=\dfrac{1}{35}$$

Then, $$P(\mbox{A draws first dime})=\dfrac37+\dfrac{6}{35}+\dfrac{1}{35}=\dfrac{22}{35}$$

$$P(\mbox{A draws dime on first draw}|\mbox{A draws first dime})=\dfrac{\dfrac37}{\dfrac{22}{35}}=\dfrac{15}{22}$$

Comment: Why P(A draws dime in the second draw) is $\frac{6}{35}$ and P(A draws dime in the third draw) is $\frac{1}{35}$

Comment: I understand this problem, but what puzzles me is the probability for drawing the first dime on the second and third draw. How do you compute these two probabilities? The second draw is said to be $\frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{3}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{5}$ Is this a typo? it should be $\frac{2}{5}$ instead of $\frac{3}{5}$

Comment: @JamesWarthington There is no typo. This is because, in second attempt he will definitely pick a dime out of remaining $6$, so it is $\dfrac36$ and the rest of the draws will be nickels, so it is $\dfrac35$. Since it already picked nickel at first which is $\dfrac47$

Comment: Thanks, then why on the third draw it is $\frac{2}{5}$ instead of $\frac{3}{5}$. He hasn't drawn any nickel before the third draw, why does the third fraction is  $\frac{2}{5}$  instead of  $\frac{3}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The probability of drawing a dime on the first draw is $\frac{3}7$, but what if the first *A*'s draw is a nickel, and then *B* draws another nickel? *A* can obtain the first dime in its second try...

Answer (score 0):

If we don't know A drew the first dime, $\frac{3}{7}$ is the correct answer.

But given that A drew the first dime, it turns to be a conditional probability.

Let $E_1=${A drew the first dime}, $E_2$={A drew a dime on the first draw}, then

$$P(E_2|E_1)=\frac{P(E_1\cap E_2)}{P(E_1)}=\frac{\frac{3}{7}}{\frac{3}{7}+\frac{4}{7}*\frac{3}{6}*\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4}{7}*\frac{3}{6}*\frac{2}{5}*\frac{1}{4}*\frac{3}{3}}=\frac{15}{22}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us model the situation. The space $\Omega$ is the space of all possibilities to extract the seven coins in order,
$$\Omega=\Big\{\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots,\omega_7)\ :\ \omega_j\in\{D,N\}\text{ and there are 3D and 4N components }\Big\}\ .$$ 
Each element (better, one element subset of $\Omega$) has the same probability, this defines a probability $\Bbb P$ on $\Omega$ (with its power set as sigma-algebra). The elements of $\omega$ are in a bijection with the subsets with $3$ elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, by mapping $\omega$ to the positions in $\omega$ where there is a D component.
Now we let the players A and B extract alternatively for each "path of the chances" $\omega\in\Omega$, so A will extract for a fixed $\omega$ its components $\omega_1,\omega_3,\omega_5,\omega_7$. An B the other ones. The question asks for the **conditional probabiltiy** $$\Bbb P(S|T)\ ,$$
where $T$ is the set corresponding to "player extracts the first D", i.e. the first D occurs on an odd indexed place, and $S$ is the the event $\{\omega\ :\ \omega_1=D\}$. It is clear that $S\subset T$. The event $T$ corresponds to the cases:

```
D******
NND****
NNNND** = NNNNDDD
```

So we ( need to) compute 
$$\Bbb P(S|T)
= \frac{\Bbb P(S\cap T)}{\Bbb P(T)}
= \frac{\Bbb P(S)}{\Bbb P(T)}
= \frac{\frac 37}
{\frac 37 
 +\frac 47\cdot \frac 36\cdot \frac 35
 +\frac 47\cdot \frac 36\cdot \frac 25\cdot \frac 14\cdot \frac 33}
=
\frac {15}{22}
\ .
$$